# Read a file and check if lines are equal to a String

Tags: java, file, minecraft, reader

My code should explain my issue thoroughly. I need to read the entire file and get each line's data then apply that data. I am having issues with reading the entire file and getting each lines data. It also sends the whole program into an infinite loop. I added some debug messages that are sent to the console. That's what the "Logger.log(")" are. They're sending debug messages to the console. Here's my code:

EDIT: I fixed the looping issue by changing "while (fileList.length != 0)" to "if (fileList.length != 0)" But now have the issue of the operation not continuing past the debug message "Logger.log("14")".

```
public void setItems(Inventory inv)
{
    try
    {
        if (!kit.getDataFolder().exists())
        {
            kit.getDataFolder().mkdirs();
        }

        Logger.log("1");

        File folder = files.getFolder("GUI Menu");
        Logger.log("2");
        if (!folder.exists())
        {
            files.createFolder("GUI Menu");
        }
        File[] fileList = folder.listFiles();
        Logger.log("3");
        if (fileList.length != 0)
        {
            Logger.log("4");
            for (File forFile : fileList)
            {
                Logger.log("5");
                File file = files.getGuiItem(forFile);
                Logger.log("6");
                if (!file.exists())
                {
                    Logger.log("Cannot open Inventory for the file");
                    return;
                }
                Logger.log("7");
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
                Logger.log("8");
                String line;
                Logger.log("9");
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    Logger.log("10");
                    ItemStack item;

                    if (line.contains("Item ID: "))
                    {
                        Logger.log("11");
                        String[] tSplit = line.split(": ");
                        String split = tSplit[1];
                        Logger.log("12");
                        if (StringCheck.isInteger(split))
                        {
                            Logger.log("13");
                            Material mat = Material.matchMaterial(split);

                            ItemStack item1 = new ItemStack(mat, 1);
                            item = item1;
                            Logger.log("14");

                            if (line.contains("Kit Name: "))
                            {
                                String[] jSplit = line.split(": ");
                                String j2split = jSplit[1];
                                Logger.log("15");

                                if (item != null && !item.equals(Material.AIR))
                                {
                                    ItemMeta meta = item.getItemMeta();

                                    meta.setDisplayName(Color.add("&6" + j2split + "&e Kit"));
                                    item.setItemMeta(meta);
                                    Logger.log("16");

                                    if (line.contains("Price: "))
                                    {
                                        String[] pSplit = line.split(": ");
                                        String p2split = pSplit[1];
                                        Logger.log("17");

                                        if (item != null && !item.equals(Material.AIR))
                                        {
                                            this.setLore(item, "&ePrice: &6" + p2split);

                                            if (line.contains("Slot Number: "))
                                            {
                                                Logger.log("18");
                                                String[] fSplit = line.split(": ");
                                                String f2split = fSplit[1];
                                                if (StringCheck.isInteger(f2split))
                                                {
                                                    Logger.log("19");
                                                    if (item != null && !item.equals(Material.AIR))
                                                    {
                                                        Logger.log("20");
                                                        if (inv.getItem(Integer.parseInt(split)) == null || inv.getItem(Integer.parseInt(split)).equals(Material.AIR))
                                                        {
                                                            inv.setItem(Integer.parseInt(split), item);
                                                        }
                                                    }

                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                br.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: `while (fileList.length != 0)` should probably be a `if` statement

Comment: Hmmm, will that fix my issue?

Comment: It will 1- Make it more readable and 2- Reduce the risk of getting into an infinite loop

Comment: Alright, changed it. Anything else that you can spot wrong with it?

Comment: I still don't know why you're using both a `BufferedReader` and `Scanner`. I'd also encourage you to make use of the [try-with-resources statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) to better manage your resources

Comment: That was a mistake using the scanner. I edited the code in the original question so it now has no Scanner. I was merely testing before with the Scanner out of desperation and forgot to remove it when asking my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using a `Scanner`, the methods you want are `hasNextLine()` and `nextLine()`. The method `hasNextLine()` will return `false` when you have read all the lines. If using a `BufferedReader` you must check that you have not exhausted the input by examining the result of reading the line. Regardless of your file reading method, you must make sure you close your reader. Here I will give you the more complex `BufferedReader` example and use `try-with-resources` to `close()` it. Like,

```
File file = new File("test.txt");
try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
    String line;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
        // ...
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And for completeness, using a `Scanner`,

```
File file = new File("test.txt");
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file)) {
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        // ...
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Parsing each line using a *regular expression*,

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Slot Number: (\\d+) Kit Name: (\\S+) Price: (\\d+) Item ID: (\\d+)",
        Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
String line = "Slot Number: 0 Kit Name: Basic Price: 50 Item ID: 385";
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
if (m.matches()) {
    int slot = Integer.parseInt(m.group(1));
    String name = m.group(2);
    int price = Integer.parseInt(m.group(3));
    int id = Integer.parseInt(m.group(4));
    System.out.printf("%s %d %d %d%n", name, id, slot, price);
}
```

Which outputs

```
Basic 385 0 50
```

Comment: I'm not sure this answers my question. I need to get all the data within the file. The file looks like this: 

Slot Number: 0
Kit Name: Basic
Price: 50
Item ID: 385

Comment: @CodaPlays Put your code to handle each line where I have `// ...`; both examples will get all the data within the file. I have not, nor do I intend to, write your parsing code for you. But I would suggest you use a *regular expression* `Pattern`.

Comment: When I pasted the code into my question, I forgot to remove the code that I was testing with. That's why the scanner was there. I have edited my questions code. Do you think my now current code will work?

Comment: Try the code. Don't edit your question to include my answer; especially since my answer is to the question: "How can I read each line in a file"...

Comment: Alright, sorry. I am new to StackOverflow so please excuse my ignorance. The code now worked correctly but does not go past the line "Logger.log("14)" in the code. It simply stops there. Do you know any reason why?

Comment: Where is the `br.close();` in my code? And why did you put one in your code? Try using a debugger. We have now reached the point where you are expected to exert some further effort to resolve these issues yourself. For example, you know a `String` causes your code to hang at "14" with your Logger; what does that have to do with reading the file?

Comment: Alright, I'll figure it out. Thanks for your help. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @CodaPlays Please try. Then read my edit. Because I wrote you a *parser*; like I said though, I used a `Pattern` (and a `Matcher`) with a regular expression based on the single line provided in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment on the other answer(Elliot's, which is entirely correct), I'll provide you with some pointers on an easy to follow/understand method to do what you want.

1. Use either implementation from Elliot's answer.
2. Make a method that takes in a `String` (a line from the file) and converts it to whatever you need.
3. In Elliot's code, replace the `// ...` line with a call to the method you created, passing in the line you just read from the file

This will keep your file-reading code very nice and clean, and will also make it easily readable. You'll also be able to reuse that code elsewhere if you ever need to, by calling that method again. If you don't know how to parse the file and get the information that you want out of it, I recommend you ask another question here on SO.

Comment: Alright, thank you for your polite answer. Will what you have suggested run for each file within the folder I am calling?

Comment: if you would like to read many files, I'd suggest adding each file name to an array, and then creating a file object in a loop, getting the name of the file to be read from the array based on the current iteration through the loop. Then, inside the loop that creates file objects and a reader of some sort, put your code that reads from a single file. 

Read in the appropriate filename from the array. 
Create a reader for that file. 
Read in the file line by line. 
Repeat.